# How to make max of y-axis a set value above the maximum value of a count using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to plot a simple bar chart of counts using ggplot2, including labels of the actual counts. This is in a regularly updated database so that the actual counts will change over time.

As a result, I want to bake in the y-axis always to be at least 5 above the maximum count when I generate the plot. I an only find how to explicitly set the axes.

Is there a way to get the behavior I am looking for?

Below is an example of what I have done

```
library(ggplot2)

x<- c("A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A", "B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A", "B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","B")

df %>% 
  mutate(x = as.factor(x)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x))+
  geom_bar()+ 
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), hjust=-1)
```

Example of defaults

[image: Example output of what I have been doing]

Example of what I want

[image: Example output of what I want to happen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could add `+5%` to the max of `n` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  count(x) %>% 
  mutate(max_x = max(n)*1.05) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x = n, y=x))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = n),  hjust=-1)+
  xlim(0, unique(df1$max_x))
```

[image]

Comment: Using a static number of 5 could be problematic if the range varies drastically each time the database is updated.  A max(n)*1.05 or another multiplier could handle more cases always making the axis x% longer

Comment: You are right. Feel free to change my answer!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use the invisible point trick, i.e. add a `geom_point` layer with transparent colored points beneath your bar charts for which you add your desired amount of "padding" to the count. This will automatically increase the range of the scale:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = factor(x))

df |>
  ggplot(aes(y = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = after_stat(count + 5)),
    stat = "count", color = "transparent"
  ) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    stat = "count",
    aes(label = after_stat(count)), hjust = -1
  )
```

[image]